# Print all nodes starting from a specific root

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure:

```
const arr = [
 {
  "id": 58,
  "parent_id": null
 },
 {
   "id": 59,
   "parent_id": 58
 },
 {
  "id": 60,
  "parent_id": 59
 },
 {
  "id": 61,
  "parent_id": 58
 },
 {
  "id": 62,
  "parent_id": 61
 },
 {
  "id": 63,
  "parent_id": 62
 },
 {
  "id": 64,
  "parent_id": 63
 }
]
```

which represents the following tree:

[image]

I want to print all the nodes from a specific root. How can I do this?

For example:

- If selecting root 58, it should print all items from 58 - 64.
- If selecting root 61, it should print items 61 - 64.

I've tried using recursion and a for loop but this seems to traverse only 1 branch of the tree.

```
const printNodes = (currItems, allItems) => {
  for (const currItem of currItems) {
    const items = arr.filter(item => item.parent_id === currItem.id)

    allItems = allItems.concat(items)

    return printNodes(items, allItems)
  }

  return allItems
}

console.log(printNodes([arr[0]], []))
```

Comment: You need to explain more. What pattern should the path go through?

Comment: @MajedBadawi It should go through all paths leading from the selected root, order of visit doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the whole array and pass the start node to your function. Then search all childs and recursively call the function again, once with every child.

```
const collectNodes = (arr, startNode, results)=>{
    results.push(startNode);
    const childs = arr.filter(item=>item.parent_id === startNode.id);
    if (childs.length) {
        childs.forEach(c => collectNodes(arr, c, results));
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(collectNodes(arr, arr[3], []))

// Prints
// {id: 61, parent_id: 58}
// {id: 62, parent_id: 61}
// {id: 63, parent_id: 62}
// {id: 64, parent_id: 63}
```

For performance reasons i would create a property `child` with an array, before iterating.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with all relations and map the `id`.

```js
const
    getNodes = parent => [parent, ...(relations[parent] || []).flatMap(getNodes)],
    data = [{ id: 58, parent_id: null }, { id: 59, parent_id: 58 }, { id: 60, parent_id: 59 }, { id: 61, parent_id: 58 }, { id: 62, parent_id: 61 }, { id: 63, parent_id: 62 }, { id: 64, parent_id: 63 }],
    relations = data.reduce((r, { id, parent_id }) => {
        if (!r[parent_id]) r[parent_id] = [];
        r[parent_id].push(id);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(getNodes(58));
console.log(getNodes(61));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```